# No Keyboard Backlight for Toshiba Qosmio X770

Tags: keyboard, backlight, toshiba

I have researched the old questions but I am still stuck. I am running Kubuntu 18.04. my question is about back light

Comment: Are you referring to a keyboard backlight or a screen backlight?

Comment: Keyboard lights at bootup but when entering kubuntu nothing is lite.

Comment: Some keyboards have a timeout. If you go into BIOS mode and leave the keyboard alone does it turn off by itself?

Comment: The Keyboard works fine for win10 but not for Kubuntu!